# Url routing with static name mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a controller name `Dashboard` and inside that controller i have an action `AdminDashboard` . Now by default url of this action becomes `/Dashboard/AdminDashboard` . I want to map this action to this url `/SupervisorDashboard`

This is what i am doing but its saying not found

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SupervisorDashboard",
            url: "SupervisorDashboard",
            defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "AdminDashboard" }
        );
```

and also how can i redirect to this page using `Url.Action`

**Global.asax**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SupervisorDashboard",
            url: "SupervisorDashboard",
            defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "AdminDashboard" }
        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)` called from anywhere? From what I see, real routing is defined in `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);` inside `Application_Start`, check that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you placed this new route definition before default route? Routes are evaluated in the same order in which they were registered. If you put default route before any of custom routes, it will be used (and since you probably don't have any `SupervisorDashboardController` in code, 404 will be returned).

`Url.Action` should work correctly, if routes are defined in correct order.

So, for this case, RouteConfig should look like this:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {           
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        // this one match /SupervisorDashboard only
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SupervisorDashboard",
            url: "SupervisorDashboard",
            defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "AdminDashboard" }
        );

        // should be last, after any custom route definition
        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: what if i didn't have any default route?

Comment: and also is this correct `Url.Action("SupervisorDashboard")` ?

Comment: No, just use `Url.Action("AdminDashboard", "Dashboard")`, routing will take care of translation to correct url.

Comment: ok but routing still not working and i also don't have any home controller and default route in my global.asax,, any idea ?

Comment: Hmm, could you edit answer and post some code related to routing? Ideally whole routing definition. Default route is usually route, which can catch all requests. It is most probably route with argument `url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"`. Such route should be placed as last, because it can match any request done to application.

Comment: added my whole global.asax . Please check